# Is it possible to define slots in neos fusion afx like you can in Vue?

Tags: fusion, neoscms, afx, vuejs-slots

In Vue.js I can define named slots for my components, besides my default slot:

```vue
<article>
  <header>
    <slot name="header">
      <h2>Default heading</h2>
    </slot>
  </header>
  <slot/>
</article>
```

and then use it like this:

```vue
<template>
  <FooArticle v-for="item in items">
    <template #heading>
      <h3>{{item}} Heading</h3>
    </template>
    <p>Just content</p>
  </FooArticle>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    FooArticle
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: ['First', 'Second']
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Is this possible with Neos Fusion, to create a mechanism like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, as you can use the `@path` decorator to overwrite a property of the wrapper element.

First you define your props and then output them in the renderer.

```php-template
prototype(Foo.Components:Article) < prototype(Neos.Fusion:Component) {

    heading = afx`<h2>Default heading</h2>`

    content = ''

    renderer = afx`
        <article>
            <header>
                {props.heading}
            </header>
            {props.content}
        </article>
    `
}
```

Then you want to override these "slots" (props) from the outside with the `@path` decorator. The whole element the decorator is defined on will override the specified prop "heading" of the wrapping element.

```php-template
prototype(Foo.Site:Home) < prototype(Neos.Fusion:Component) {
    items = ${['First', 'Second']}

    renderer = afx`
        <Neos.Fusion:Loop items={props.items}>
            <Foo.Components:Article>
                <Neos.Fusion:Fragment @path="heading">
                    <h3>{item} heading</h3>
                </Neos.Fusion:Fragment>
                <p>just some content</p>
            </Foo.Components:Article>
        </Neos.Fusion:Loop>
    `
}
```

FYI, we use a [`Neos.Fusion:Fragment`](https://neos.readthedocs.io/en/stable/References/NeosFusionReference.html#neos-fusion-fragment) object to define the path decorator, so the fragment does not render any additional markup like an enclosing `<div>`. In this simple case, where we only want to render a single element into the slot, we could have omitted the fragment and just set the `@path="heading"` directly to the `<h3>`.

- [Working example in FusionPen](https://fusionpen.punkt.de/fusionpen/86ce3c4e37747fe78013b720169ed7a761dc73b9.html)
- [Fusion AFX Docs](https://github.com/neos/fusion-afx)
- [Neos Fusion Docs](https://docs.neos.io/cms/manual/rendering/fusion)